# linear independence and dependence in relation to fields

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that every set that is contained in a linear independent set is also linear independent and that every set that contains in a linear dependent set is also linear dependent but what the field the set is under has to do with it?

For example:

Let F be a field and another field is K$\subset $ F and V a vector space under K(also F) and $A = (v_1,v_2,...,v_n)
$ is a set of vectors.

Say, A is a linear independent set under K does it mean that A a linear independent set under F too?

What about the other way around?
Say, A is a linear independent set under F does it mean that A a linear independent set under K too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is one dimensional over the reals (obviously) but infinite dimensional over the rationals.  Specifically:  the elements $\{1,\sqrt 2, e\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: For the first question: no (for example $1,i$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{R}$, but not over $\Bbb C$). For the second question, yes: it follows almost by definition.